# MFC Titlebar icon having transparency applied

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm in the process of updating an old (dates back to at least Visual Studio 6) MFC application to use a ribbon (vs the old toolbar/menu).

After I did the top level UI swap, the applications icon in the titlebar is having the same level of transparency applied to it by windows 7 as the remainder of the titlebar leaving it very washed out looking.  If used in the application ribbon, the icon is shown normally.

The same thing happens when I replace the icon in an otherwise empty MFC application that was created by the VS wizard.

That implies that the problem is with the icon; most likely that MS is now requiring more data/different image sizes/bitrates/etc in the .ico file than the legacy ico file contains.  The current icon is 32x32 pixels in size and in 16 color (4 bit) format.

What do I need to add to the icon to make it behave properly in an MFC ribbon application.

Comment: Windows Vista introduced PNG-support for ICO files (see [The evolution of the ICO file format, part 4: PNG images](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/22/10079192.aspx)). Have you tried using that already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a version with it's own alpha channel.  Converting the icon image to a 32bit/pixel format resulted in it displaying normally.